# Removing EF Core Migration removes columns the Migration had nothing to do with

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class that includes 2 properties: `Value` and `Description`. These 2 properties were added to the class a couple of Migrations back and there was never a problem.

Today, while working on a branch I noticed that when I added a new Migration it was scaffolded to once again add the columns, so I started doing some testing.

Starting from the current baseline, with no entity changes, if I add a Migration called "Test", I get this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace AgWare.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class Test : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Which is correct, I haven't made any changes to my Models. Git only shows the new Migration and its Designer.cs files as added, with no changes to the Snapshot. Now, if I run Remove Migration, the Test Migration is removed but suddenly Git says that my Snapshot has changed, with the following lines having been deleted from the `modelBulder` entry for the above-mentioned class:

```
b.Property<decimal?>("Value")
    .HasColumnType("Money");

b.Property<string>("Description")
    .HasMaxLength(75);
```

So removing a Migration which had nothing to do with these properties somehow results in updating the Snapshot to reflect that they have been removed for some reason. This means when I add another Migration it will generate code to create these columns again, which won't work since they already exist. What could be the cause of this? I want to figure this out now so this doesn't become a reoccurrence for all future Migrations.

Comment: It looks at the Snapshot and compares it to the current Model state, not the actual db schema. I ran the above steps with a connection string for a brand new database with no tables and it did the exact same thing.